# My Deployed website is only showing readme.md on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, deployment

My deployed website is showing only readme.md. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
website: https://ssaba96.github.io/WDI-P2-funny-predictions/

I have searched stack overflow for this problem but hav not got a clear answer.

All code is visible through this link 
https://github.com/ssaba96/WDI-P2-funny-predictions

Comment: U have no html file in the root dir. And it seems to me that this is a express/nodejs app. This kind of site dont run on github pages.

Comment: As @Marc said, [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) only hosts static html pages, which means it looks for an index.html file in your directory to load. You don't have one and therefore reverts to the readme. If you're looking for a free site to host your node app try [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), which can easily deploy straight from your git repo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your express server file index.js you are static serving the public folder, when I think you really want to serve the views folder? Try just putting

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Comment: i tried deployed website with heroku but its displaying error above

Comment: oooh ok if you're deploying to heroku you need to use port 5000 for heroku to see your build and its recommended to put your build files in a /build folder. I see you have your Procfile already and it looks good. You should check this out and follow it step by step: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

Comment: I visited the link you mentioned. Still confused as I followed steps but problem still not solved :( . However, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hey, can you edit your question or create a new one with the heroku error you received when you deployed? We can take a look at it.

Comment: Hey, I've mentioned it in my new question.